# How to restrict, Selected Category Products Purchase only from selected Zip/Pin Codes area?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, zipcode

The selected category of products purchase only from selected Pin/Zip Codes area, how can i do that,,

eg:

Category: Leaves 
Zip code : 0214578,2849648

Suppose the customer order from the zip code: 32212, Don't able to place the order.

Answer (score 0):

Set the the following conditions for the rule BUT this will only limit to the Shipping Postcode (ie Anyone can get the deal providing they ship to the desired postcodes)

**Conditions**
If **ALL**  of these conditions are TRUE :
Shipping Postcode **is one of** 0214578,2849648

**Actions**
If **ALL**  of these conditions are **TRUE** :
Category  **is** Leaves

Comment: It's not working, other zip code also placed order like  zip code : 444444

Comment: I will check on my test site  later on as this should work.  When you say it is not working - is the discount being applied or NOT appled.

Comment: Checked and it is working perfectly for logged in customers.  However, if I fill in the guest checkout NO discount is applied therefore Magento can only process the rule before a checkout process begins.

Comment: Conditions : https://snag.gy/5U87yr.jpg   Actions: https://snag.gy/FOKeHw.jpg,,, is my workout right?

Comment: I am added zip code like, 001,002,003,004,006,007 into shopping cart price rule. I am using zip code 788, this is also working, i listed zip code only able to purchase the products in particular category of products. If it's working for you may I see the screen shot if you insert wrong zip code error message?

Comment: Check out screen shots : https://snag.gy/N26aeT.jpg

Comment: Think I misunderstood your original question.  Are you trying to restrict the purchase of these items to specific zip codes?  If so then the standard Magento Cart Rules will not do this - it is only designed to offer a discount.  Have a look at the Amasty Shipping Restriction module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63654/discussion-between-zus-and-hejhog).